# Run application in current drive in Windows 10

Tags: hard-drive

I want to make a .bat file which launches many ohter .bat files and .exe files on a USB. But the USB is every time on a different Drive. I want it to lauch files from current drive like F: or G:

Something like this

run %drive%\Take\file.bat

Thanks

Comment: Try with adding this at first `cd %~dp0`.

Comment: Where is the batch file stored in relation to the commands it will execute?

Comment: If the batch file is stored-on and launched-from the USB, you don't need to do anything. Just don't specify any drive-letter, like `\path` rather than `H:\path`.

Comment: From my personal experience, if you format the drive in drive management, and give it a name and a letter, that no other USB will ever try to use (like X: or Z:), the drive letter does never change.